# Scrollable LinearLayout height limitation

Tags: android, android-linearlayout

I am adding TextViews in a LinearLayout programmatically and I want to ensure that if the TextViews exceed a certain number the user will be able to scroll down. I included the LinearLayout inside a ScrollView which works fine up to a certain limit. After that limit, the top views are not shown at all.

I am using the following code:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.linear_layout_with_scrollview);


    for (int i = 0; i < 500; i++) {
        createView(String.valueOf(i));
    }
}



private void createView(String text){

    TextView tv = new TextView(this);

    LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

    lp.setMargins(0,15,0,0);


    tv.setLayoutParams(lp);

    tv.setText(text);
    tv.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP,20);
    LinearLayout layout=findViewById(R.id.linear_layout);
    layout.addView(tv);

}
```

and for the layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<ScrollView android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/linear_layout"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical" 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
</LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

This is not the actual code I am using but a simplified version to demonstrate the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try This One. i hope work...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="match_parent"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<LinearLayout android:layout_height="matchparent" android:layout_width="match_parent"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">


<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/linear_layout"
android:layout_gravity="center"
android:gravity="center"
android:orientation="vertical" 
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">
</LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Comment: Indeed that trick worked. I wonder why you have to add this extra LinearLayout. Do you have an answer on this or it is a product of experimentation?

Comment: second one :)))

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend to use a RecyclerView. You can find a simple example [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/recyclerview).

This is the best method to handle big lists.

Answer (score 1):

use `android:fillViewport="true"`in your `scrollview`

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<ScrollView 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/linear_layout"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical" 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
</LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Comment: The addition of the above attribute did not produce the desired result.

Comment: @Saloom when the views are vanished, do you get any error or exception ? If no then there is an issue of recycling of views and like other answer suggested it would be better to use recycler view instead.